# Unable to add/import additional python library datacompy in aws glue

Tags: python-3.x, aws-glue, python-module, aws-glue-spark

i am trying to import additional python library - datacompy in to the glue job which use version 2 with below step

1. Open the AWS Glue console.
2. Under Job parameters, added the following:
3. For Key, added --additional-python-modules.
   For Value, added datacompy==0.7.3, s3://python-modules/datacompy-0.7.3.whl.

```
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

import datacompy

from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME = "net.snowflake.spark.snowflake"

## @params: [JOB_NAME, URL, ACCOUNT, WAREHOUSE, DB, SCHEMA, USERNAME, PASSWORD]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME', 'URL', 'ACCOUNT', 'WAREHOUSE', 'DB', 'SCHEMA','additional-python-modules'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)
```

but the job return the error

```
module not found error no module named 'datacompy'
```

how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are installing datacompy twice.  You should be able to get by with just `datacompy==0.7.31.0.2` and skip the whl file.   However, if datacompy is a c based lib you might need to go down the whl route.   Also, do the logs indicate an install failure of any kind?

Comment: Hello @BobHaffner i tried with your step, but it failing .. i didn't find specific logs for failure.. the job failing initially when it invoke 'import datacompy'.. i am adding those job initiation part in the step here.. so one question do we need to add any logic to read from args to install lib in the code?

Comment: so using Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue Version 2.0), the following allows me to import datacompy.  For Key, `--additional-python-modules`  For Value, `datacompy==0.7.3`.    No, you don't have to do anything in your code to install it

Comment: i am using the same version and configuration, but it fails with same import error

Comment: That's crazy. I wonder if the Job is caching the old config.  Maybe try to create a whole new Job?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem and I agree, that's crazy. @BobHaffner could you share your whole job run configuration (screenshot form Glue 'Edit job' window for example, of all settings)? Would be greatly appreciated. I tried running new Glue job with multiple changes to config and nothing helped

Comment: @BobHaffner @cloud_hari what type of Glue jobs are you using? Is it `Python shell`? I started to worry that this option might not work on `Python shell` job run types, only on Spark ones

Comment: Hi @PD I'll post some screenshots in a bit.  We're both using Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue Version 2.0).   However, I've installed libs with python shell jobs before.  I recall the steps being slightly different.  Have you tried putting `datacompy==0.7.3` in the Python Library Path box instead of --additional-python-modules?

Comment: @PD I submitted an answer with screenshots

Comment: Thank you @BobHaffner, I really appreciate your help. However it still does not work for Python shell. I tried putting it in ` Python Library Path` as you suggested but this box expects path to S3 and results in `ParamValidationError` when I try to run the job. Do you have maybe any other ideas?

Comment: @PD I had to go the whl file route to get it to work in python shell.  See my edited answer

Comment: @cloud_hari Did you set up Glue in a private VPC w/o internet access by chance?  see this for more details https://medium.com/@jasonli.lijie/aws-glue-run-python-shell-job-with-external-libraries-in-private-vpc-459b9849c235

Answer (score 1):

With Spark 2.4, Python 3 (Glue Version 2.0)

I set the following Job Parameter

[image]

Then I can import it my Job like so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datacompy


df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,2), columns=['a','b'])

compare = datacompy.Compare(df1, df2, join_columns='a')


print(compare.report())
```

and when I check the CW Log for the Job Run

[image]

If you're using a Python Shell Job, try the following

Create a datacompy whl file or you can download it from [PYPI](https://pypi.org/project/datacompy/#files)

upload that file to an S3 bucket

Then enter the path to the s3 whl file in the **Python library path** box

`s3://my-bucket/datacompy-0.8.0-py3-none-any.whl`