# send data from s3 to postres rds with glue

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-glue

I'm trying to create an automated pipeline with aws. I'm able to get my csv file into my s3 bucket and that automatically triggers a lambda function to send the csv to my glue job. The glue job then turns the csv into a dataframe with pyspark. you cannot use psycopg2, pandas or sqlalchemy, or else glue will give an error saying the module doesn't exist. I have a postgres rds setup in aws rds. This is what i have so far

```
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from setuptools import setup
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["VAL1", "VAL2"])
file_name = args['VAL1']
bucket_name = args["VAL2"]
file_path = "s3a://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, file_name)
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, sep=',', inferSchema=True, header=True)
df.drop("index")
url = "my rds endpoint link"
```

i have tried almost a dozen solutions before asking on stackoverflow. So any help would be amazing

Comment: Did you try a `df.write...` jdbc approach?  and yeah, some py modules (eg sqlalchemy) have to be added/installed

Comment: See this answer for installing additional py modules https://stackoverflow.com/a/71404169/3437504

Comment: when i go to add job parameters the "--additional-python-modules" isn't there

Comment: You need to add it in the Key "Box" and then add sqlalchemy to the Value Box

Comment: i set the key to --additional-python-modules and the value to sqlalchemy==3.0 and im still getting the error of no module found. did i type something wrong? i also put in the value slot what the link you sent said which was datacompy==0.7.3 and i got the same error

Comment: i also just now tried without putting a version and i still get the error

Comment: And this is a Spark job (not Python Shell)?

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: Do the Logs reveal anything?  Like an attempt to install sqlalchemy?  Any reason why your Glue Job wouldn't have access to pypi?  Which Glue Version are you using?

Comment: when i go to view all logs it says there is no log stream. and im using glue3.0

Comment: Ok, i'm fresh out of ideas on the module install.  I would submit a whole new question if you want to get that piece working.   I'll go ahead and post a pyspark dataframe to rds solution in case that helps

Answer (score 0):

I used this `df.write` approach before.  Starting where you left off with your pyspark dataframe

```
jdbc_url = 'jdbc:postgresql://<instance_name>.xxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/<db_name>' 

(df.write.format('jdbc').option('url', 'jdbc_url') 
                        .option('user', 'myUsername') 
                        .option('password', 'myPassword') 
                        .option('dbtable', 'myTable') 
                        .option('driver', 'org.postgresql.Driver') 
                         .mode('append').save())
```